# Generic conversion function doesn't seem to work with Guids

Tags: c#, .net, generics, typeconverter

I have the following code:

```
public static T ParameterFetchValue<T>(string parameterKey)
{
    Parameter result = null;

    result = ParameterRepository.FetchParameter(parameterKey);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result.CurrentValue, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
}
```

The type of **`result.CurrentValue` is string**.  I would like to be able to convert it to Guid but I keep getting the error:

> Invalid cast from System.String to System.Guid

This works perfectly with primitive data types.
Is there any way to **make this work for non-primitive data types**?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

How about:

```
T t = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(text);
```

Works fine for `Guid` and most other types.

Comment: Be careful with using ConvertFromInvariantString.  If your type is a DateTime and you have international date formats, this will blow up.  I just tracked down a really hard-to-find bug based upon this answer.

Comment: @DPeden indeed, they must match - my usage here was using invariant on the assumption that serialised data should usually be in an invariant format

Comment: Yep, agreed.  I still upvoted your answer as it is very useful.  Just pointing out this potential gotcha for others as it burned me.