# set last access time

Tags: c#, permissions, filesystems

I am trying to record the last access time of all the apps intalled in a pc, i have the next code:

```
System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTime(appList[offSet], DateTime.Now);
```

I understand that i need to give permissions to make this operation, i alreay try a manifest file with the next line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But when i run my program, the next error appears:

> Error ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm, a quick Google search on your error gave me the answer.

Comment: if it is the FileIOPermission f, it did not work

Comment: In fact, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713825/run-as-administrator-requireadministrator-clickonce-emulating-system-time is a dup.

Comment: @lc. He's not trying to change the system time... he needs to disable ClickOnce deployment. Btw, I hate answers that doesn't solve problems.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Yes, the exact task to be done is different, but the means/issue (requiring admin privileges from ClickOnce) is exactly the same and the answer will be as well. If that doesn't qualify as a dup, we may as well have 1000 different questions enumerating different reasons to need admin privileges...

Comment: @lc. Yes, but the answer stated there does not solve his problem. And yes, different reasons may mean different solutions or approach to a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to your project properties in Visual Studio, in the security tab **un-check** "Enable ClickOnce security settings". i think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The account under which this application is running is what needs the permissions.

Setting `requestedExecutionLevel` will only work if the account has the required permissions.

Comment: how can i grant the permissions?