# kernelbase error when forcing wpf app to run as administrator

Tags: wpf, .net-core, runas

we have a wpf application which is written with .net core 3.1 .
so for forcing wpf to run as admin we added appmanifest file and changed :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and below line added to project.csproj file :

```
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
```

after doing all of before step and publishing application we got an error in windows eventviewer :
Faulting application name: WpfVideoCourseApp.Presentation.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x60776cd9
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1151, time stamp: 0x891df6d3
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034ed9
Faulting process id: 0x2ac8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7a5852476cbd1
Faulting application path: E:\VideoCourseApp\WpfVideoCourseApp.Presentation.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d9b3e20f-55dc-4dd2-b0ad-40e940dedaa6
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

but afterall i should say that :  app runs without any problem when using debug files(problem is all about published version of application)

Update :
in publish when i run app , app try to write something in windows document folder and access will denied(but thats not happening when running debug code)
actualy i added manifest file for having permission to reading and writing my files in some special path's(like document folder) but it just work in debug

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't run a ClickOnce deployed application with administrative privileges.

As a workaround, you may consider to [implement your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19180975/7252182) to start a new process as an admininstrator or choose another deployment strategy.

Comment: iam not using clickOnce , and my implemetation result as same as  you said(new process..) , both works on debug and both does not work on publish.
in publish when i run app , app try to write something in windows document folder and access will denied(but thats not happening when running debug code)

Comment: So how exactly do you publish the app?