# Properties.Settings.Default.Save() store the user.config file in a directory with a hash

Tags: c#, path, settings, properties.settings

I try to save user settings. To save some data I used this code:

```
Properties.Settings settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
settings.Key1 = "value";
settings.Save();
```

but it saves the user.config file under the following path:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\[CompanyName]\[ExeName]_Url_[some_hash]\[Version]\user.config
```

this with the `_Url_[some_hash]` is pretty ugly, how can I remove it?

Comment: You can't. That is how it works.

Comment: Where I tried it the first time, it worked without `_null_[some hash]`

Comment: If it is a user setting it will be saved there. Perhaps an application setting affects the app.config (not sure however).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

see more info here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know if there used to be an answer on that msdn page, or if it's somehow there and I'm not seeing it. I don't see an answer on that msdn page, and I think this answer should be updated (including writing, or copy/pasting the relevant information) or rejected as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can!
Just follow [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265271/custom-path-of-the-user-config) that explain everything in full details, then you have to modify the property UserConfigPath as follows:

```
        private string UserConfigPath
    {
        get
        {
            System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo versionInfo;
            string strUserConfigPath, strUserConfigFolder;

            strUserConfigPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create);
            versionInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            strUserConfigPath = Path.Combine(strUserConfigPath, versionInfo.CompanyName, versionInfo.ProductName, versionInfo.ProductVersion, "user.config");
            strUserConfigFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(strUserConfigPath);
            if(!Directory.Exists(strUserConfigFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strUserConfigFolder);
            return strUserConfigPath;
        }
    }
```

In this way you build the path from scratch. 
You should also modify the method CreateEmptyConfig in order to have a default action when the user.config file is not found.