# UserSettings lost when application moved - strongname

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

In my company users are opening applications from a network drive. To update (override) these applications every user has to close the app.

To avoid that I created a app that finds the newest version by foldername. For example:

```
Folder: 1.0
Folder: 1.0.1
Folder: 1.0.2
Folder: 1.2
Folder: 2.0

AppLauncher.exe
```

If I click AppLauncher.exe the app in the folder 2.0 launches.
The problem is that the UserSettings are always lost on a new version because the application is on another filepath (versionfolder).

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759018/user-settings-reset-when-the-application-is-moved) the solution mentioned was to strong-name the application.
I can't to that because signing my app means that I have to sign all the other assemblies to. Thats not doable in my case.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you try copying the folder and saving it with different name? That may replicate the user settings as well

Comment: Brr, way to dig an ever deeper hole.  Strong-naming is too simple to not consider.  Programmers tend to assume it requires a certificate and code-signing, it doesn't.

Comment: How can I strong-name without code-signing?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade?view=netframework-4.7.2)

This method merges previous version settings with current settings (in memory). You will probably want to save the resulting settings.

I have this code in my program.cs:

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        //Other stuff
}
```

Comment: That is not likely to help since the app is in a completely different directory. Without a strong name the storage location for the user.config file has a very different hash value.  Upgrade() only works when the EXE assembly version is incremented.

Comment: you should add if(Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired) { ..upgrade.. }