# How to Choose Application Configuration File Save Location?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2013/2015, when you compile your program `exe` it saves the `config file` to its `\bin\` folder.

When you move your program `exe` to a location like `C:\Program Files\` and run it, it saves the `config file` to `%appdata%` `\AppData\Local\`.

Using C# or Visual Studio settings, how do I tell the `exe` to always save the `config file` to its current folder and not `%appdata%`?

I want to make the program portable and not use `%appdata%`.

---

#### \bin\ Folder

[image: bin folder]

---

#### AppData Folder

[image: appdata folder]

[image: appdata user config]

Comment: How do you "move your program `exe` to a location like `C:\Program Files\`"

Comment: Cut and paste it out of the \bin\release\ folder to C:\Program Files\My Program\.

Comment: Do you mean to say `config` is automatically created by your exe? I would recommend to publish and install rather than manual copy and paste! `config` files in output directory are created on building the application. So, if you copy you need to copy the config as well.

Comment: When I run the `exe` it automatically creates a `user.config` in `%appdata%`.

Comment: There must be a code to handle that right? This is not a default action I believe.

Comment: If you are manually creating a `Configuration` object and calling `Save()` to it, you can set the `FilePath` property of this `Configuration` object to your desired location (to possibly `AssemblyLocation`).

Comment: I believe it's default. I use `Settings.Default.Save();` when saving strings and controls in the program.

Comment: That's what I need it to do. How do I set `FilePath` property?

Comment: Ah there you go! This way of saving configs cannot be overriden. It will always save in %appdata%. What could be a work around is you can write a code to read this configuration and create a duplicate configuration with same data. I can you help you with a code which can do that. But, it is just a work around and there is no fix for your actual problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom path of the user.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265271/custom-path-of-the-user-config)

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks, I will look over all of this.

Answer (score -2):

you can change the output path of your build ...

go to project properties >> build tab >> under output section you can change the output path of your build, so it will creates the build at one place with your all files and make it portable

Comment: That's all you need to do? Just keep the original `.exe.config` with it? That's not some kind of temporary config?

Comment: you can use build events for that matter : go through the links below https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx  
       <*>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx

Comment: This only affects the compilation directory, it has absolutely no effect on runtime behavior, or anything else.