# How modify user.config from AppData folder with another application?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8, configurationmanager, user.config

I want to edit the `user.config` file from the installer or a test that is not part of the application with the config I want to edit. Therefore I need a path for `user.config`.
Path to user.config is like this: `c:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\SomeApp\SomeAppName.exe_StrongName_2ndz3ofoffkd0gg0sv1qxyrthr3yi236\2.4.2.0\`.

With `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(...)` I get just `*.exe.config` path from installation folder and not AppData.

The second option is to fold the path. I can get everything except the correct StrongName hash `2ndz3ofoffkd0gg0sv1qxyrthr3yi236` which does not match the StrongName (PublicKeyToken) from the assembly.

Can you advise me to programmatically change `user.config`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265271/custom-path-of-the-user-config

Comment: Thanks Hans, but this solution is not what I need and does not fulfill the backward compatibility with already existing code.

Answer (score 0):

The following method can potentially help you:

```
public void UpdateUserSettings(string key, string value)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();  
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\user.config"; 
        Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;  
        if (settings[key] == null)  
        {  
            settings.Add(key, value);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            settings[key].Value = value;  
        }

        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);  
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Error writing user settings");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution does not work on the `user.config` of the second application located in AppData.

Comment: Hmm then you could try to point the path to the AppData folder.

Comment: As I mentioned in question, this was the second option where getting the hash for StrongName is a problem.